# Runtime Error: Runtime ErrorSegmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++

[LINK TO THE ACTUALL PROBLEM](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/display-longest-name/0/?category%5B%5D=Strings&difficulty%5B%5D=-2&page=1&sortBy=submissions&query=category%5B%5DStringsdifficulty%5B%5D-2page1sortBysubmissions#)
I am trying to solve a question on codechef but getting a runtime error. Although when i executed same code on virtual studio code, no error was observed.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std; 
   int main()
  {
    int t;
     cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
       
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        string s[n],b;
        int i=0;
        while(i<n)
        {
            i++;
            cin>>s[i];
            if(i==0) b=s[0];
            else {
                if(b.length()<=s[i].length()) b=s[i];
                }
            
        }
        cout<<b;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int n; cin>>n;string s[n]` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time value, not a runtime variable.  Instead, `std::vector<std::string> s(n);` should be used.  You should learn C++ from good books, not sites such as geeksforgeeks.

Comment: Why do people keep on sticking `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);` into their code without knowing what it does? Especially when not knowing *where* precisely to stick it. Do yourself a favor and forget about these statements for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are incrementing `i` and then using it for reading the string `s[i]`, so at one point it reads for the element `n+1` which is not allocated so the error that occurs here is `Segmentation Error`.

What you have to do is increment the `i` after reading the string `s[i]`. You can correct this by moving the `i++;` statement to the end of the while block.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
  int t;
  cin>>t;
  while(t--){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    string s[n],b;
    int i=0;
    while(i<n){
      cin>>s[i];
      if(i==0)
        b=s[0];
      else
        if(b.length()<=s[i].length())
          b=s[i];
      i++;
    }
    cout<<b;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string s[n]` -- This is not valid C++.

Comment: I did that but it is still showing that particular error

Comment: @theWellHopeErr

Answer (score 0):

@theWellHopeErr's answer is correct and gets accepted on geeksforgeeks when the fast i/o lines are removed. I have commented them out below.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
  int t;
  cin>>t;
  while(t--){
    //ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    //cin.tie(NULL);
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    string s[n],b;
    int i=0;
    while(i<n){
      cin>>s[i];
      if(i==0)
        b=s[0];
      else
        if(b.length()<=s[i].length())
          b=s[i];
      i++;
    }
    cout<<b<<"\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Also, `string s[n]` is not to be done. Always better to save memory. This can be done just by storing the max length in a variable `maxLen` and updating your `result` only when you encounter a longer string

```
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    string result;
    int maxLen = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        if(s.length() > maxLen)
        {
            maxLen = s.length();
            result = s;
        }
        
    }
     cout<<result<<"\n";
```